# Read a point (char `.`) with SAS

Tags: string, sas

I am trying to read a file in SAS where one of the variables is a string and contains blanks and points like. I am not able to read the `.`. There is any way to do it?
I tried with `proc import` and with `var $1.` but it gives blanks instead of points.

Comment: Could you paste the code you use to read the data in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal character informat will convert periods into blanks.  This will make it work similar to how SAS treats period for numeric variables. To preserve the periods as the value of the character variable use the `$CHAR` informat instead.

```
data want ;
  input id c1 :$10. c2 :$char10. ;
cards;
1 a b 
2 . .
;
```